# SU Tag Merge Request: [monitors] to [monitor]

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

Really just a cosmetic thing, I think `[monitors](19)` should be merged into `[monitor](290)`. It makes sense not to fragment the tags based on a plural. I guess, as well, this should be added to the [list of tag synonyms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50088/official-repository-of-tag-synonyms) (when it's implemented).

Comment: Do any of the questions relate to monitoring software or anything other than a physical monitor?

Comment: @Jon: No, I have checked all 19, and they all are talking about a physical monitor.

Comment: That sounds good, then. Since you have >= 500 rep on SU, you could do this yourself (I don't have enough rep to help, unfortunately).

Comment: @Jon: I would, but I don't want to unnecessarily bump everything to the front page. Maybe that's just me though...

Comment: Has a tag-hierarchy been discussed? Like, tagging a question "c#-3.0" would automatically include it for queries for "c#" or ".net"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, Super User has a multiple monitors tag: [**[multiple-monitors]**](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/multiple-monitors) (435 questions).  This is the tag to use for discussing setups where multiple monitors are being used simultaneously.  We use the [**[monitoring]**](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/monitoring) tag for questions about monitoring software, but they can be easily confused so it's good to watch out for that.

Several of the existing **[monitors]** questions already have the **[multiple-monitors]** tag as well, and a couple of the others should have the multiple instead of the singular.  I've fixed those manually, and batch-retagged the **[monitors]** tag into [**[monitor]**](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/monitor).